# How can I get an object out of more than one JSON array in PHP?

Tags: php, github, github-api

I'm new to StackOverflow, so I apologize if I'm not formatting this correctly. I'm using the GitHub API and my goal is to get a list of a user's repositories in a dropdown form that they can select from.

Let's say the repository list URL is https://api.github.com/users/MY_GITHUB_USERNAME/repos (The way I sat things up I can get the repo URL by doing `$userdata->repos_url`). When I use the following:

```
$curl1 = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $userdata->repos_url);
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'User-Agent: MY_WEBSITE_HERE Addon Developer OAuth'
    ));
        curl_setopt($curl1,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'User-Agent: MY_WEBSITE_HERE Addon Developer OAuth');
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
        curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $cont1 = curl_exec($curl1);
    curl_close($cont1);
    echo $cont1;
```

It responds with the following:

```
[
  {
    (information I don't need)
    "full_name": "github-username/this-is-what-i-want",
    (information I don't need)
  }
]
```

I only have one repository at the moment. What I want to do is make a code that echos only the `full_name` and if there's more than one array echo each one. (All arrays will have `full_name`.)

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode it to an array, then loop through the arrays until you get to what you want:

```
$data=json_decode($cont1, true);  <~~~ tells php to decode the JSON into an array

$results=$data['FirstArray']['SecondArray']['NumResultsReturned']; <~~ most JSON's have a value showing how many arrays got sent back to you in the results.  You didn't give a true data example as a reply, so can't give exacts on these fields for you.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry I wasn't clear enough, your method may work however the JSON arrays don't seem to be named. [Here's the full JSON in question](https://api.github.com/users/therealdonovan/repos), however users may have more than one Github repository so it may show more than one array. What I'm looking for is to get the `full_name` from all arrays.